# Xcode publish error

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I did the project in Unity. In Unity everything is OK. When I publish for iOS and open it in Xcode, the app opens normal, but when I hit the button to load another scene, this error appears:

> Unloading 17 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 1736.
>           Total: 1.796250 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.078083 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.040708 ms MarkObjects: 1.165125 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.511500 ms)
>   2017-02-16 14:48:53.792517 gazin[2005:449123] schedule invalidation 
>       -> applicationWillResignActive()

How can I fix it?